# phpmailerException with message 'Invalid address'

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am new to PHPMailer. It is working well on my localhost but not on live.

I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'phpmailerException' with message 'Invalid address: ' in /directoryhere/test/public_html/scripts/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php:498 Stack trace: #0 /directoryhere/test/public_html/scripts/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php(438): PHPMailer->AddAnAddress('to', '', '') #1 /directoryhere/test/public_html/scripts/include.php(189): PHPMailer->AddAddress('', '') #2 /directoryhere/test/public_html/forgot.php(49): send_mail() #3 /directoryhere/test/public_html/index.php(141): include('/home1/test...') #4 {main} thrown in /directoryhere/test/public_html/scripts/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php on line 498

This is the line of code

`/directoryhere/test/public_html/scripts/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php:498`:

```
if (!self::ValidateAddress($address)) {
      $this->SetError($this->Lang('invalid_address').': '. $address);
      if ($this->exceptions) {
        throw new phpmailerException($this->Lang('invalid_address').': '.$address);
      }
      if ($this->SMTPDebug) {
        echo $this->Lang('invalid_address').': '.$address;
      }
      return false;
    }
```

`/directoryhere/test/public_html/scripts/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php(438)`:

```
    public function AddAddress($address, $name = '') {
    return $this->AddAnAddress('to', $address, $name);
  }
```

Could anyone help me what may be the possible cause of this?

Comment: Do I need a new mail host?

Comment: That error message is showing that you're not passing in an email address at all, so check your calling code, not PHPMailer.

Comment: Well, what **is** the address you throw in?

Answer (score 0):

@Synchro @m02ph3u5 Thank you for pointing that out! It is working well now. The problem is in the submit code . The email value is empty and yet the submit button is firing when the page loads. So what I did is to load first the form, catch if email input was empty, if not empty then the submit button was enable and ready to fire.

I just added this code of line here before the submission and calling the mail function:

```
if(isset($_POST["retrieve"])) { //name of button

//submission and calling mail function here

}
```